# Is it possible to use VScode as a remote editor for git?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

The setup is the following:

A windows machine with VS code installed.

A Linux machine where the code is.

I connect with the VS code to the Linux machine.

Can the git on the Linux machine use the remove VS code as an editor?

Found this link but it did not say how to do such configuration:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/933

Also this link did not helped me:
https://github.com/roiderats/vscode-remote-remote

I tried from the VS code terminal the following command:
`git --mergetool -t "code --wait"`
but I get the following output:
`Unknown merge tool code --wait`

I tried from the VS code terminal the following:
`git config --global core.editor "code --wait"`
Git tries to use vim as editor.

Comment: Define "did not help me", please. The script in there looks like it's exactly what you're looking for (a command to open an arbitrary remote file in the "remote remote" VS instance). Does that not work stand-alone? Or does it not work when used as the text editor?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh

Comment: I don't have this directory on the linux machine:
`"/tmp/vscode_remote_opener`
Also how to I use that script with git?

Comment: Your specified command `git config --global core.editor "code --wait"` is the right way to configure this, and I'm actually using it that way. Maybe you have this value set in your repository's `.git/config` overriding the global value? What's the output of `git config core.editor`?

Comment: And as a side note: this is not really related to remote usage, you could set this up for a local git repository that way as well.

Comment: Code (VS code) is not installed on the Linux machine. So that generates the error "Unknown merge tool code --wait".
But I can run from a terminal in VS code (VS code is on windows) which is connected to the Linux machine to "code" command.
For the local case it works i.e you have VS code on the same machine as the code you are working on. In that case git config --global core.editor "code --wait" works.
For my case I think VS code should have a special setting to create a connection git-code when git is on Machine A and code is on Machine B.

Comment: Exactly how did you connect the VS Code application on the Windows machine to the Linux machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that my mistake was that a gave the git difftool or git mergetool command from the Linux machine at that caused the error: `Unknown merge tool code --wait`

**Solution: Give the git difftool or git mergetool command from the terminal in VS code. It will work then.**

Follow this link for the settings:
https://www.roboleary.net/vscode/2020/09/15/vscode-git.html

Comment: Can you give example code for this?

Answer (score -2):

The default practice when working with Git would be to install `Git for Windows` on your Windows machine, clone the repo to the Windows machine and then edit the git repo directly on the Windows side.

You can of course set up a SAMBA-share on the Linux side to access the Git-repo remotely using VS Code on your Windows machine.

But this is frowned upon in the latest git client versions that will give you warnings when not working with cloned repos stored in your user profile `~`.

Comment: This doesn’t answers the question. Furthermore, the “normal” depends of the use case. What you expose is simply the “easy” way, which was not the case here.

Comment: Expanded on the answer about how to work with the Linux version remote from Windows.

Comment: VSCode has a remote mode that this question refers to. This answer is irrelevant.

Comment: @ZachB It remains to be seen what mode of remote connection Vasi has actually used...

Comment: The question is tagged with [vscode-remote], which refers to its native capability: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview

Comment: It's not the first time tagging is done wrong (which might be the case here). So just let's wait for Vasi to respond to my question. I'm sure he's a better judge of what he was asking about.